# Manually execute php script without running it through ssh

Tags: php, sql

My web host has disabled ssh and commandline. I have tried using a cron task but to no avail. I'm trying to install a wiki extension and it is requiring me to execute a script named update.php in order to complete the installation. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with php code. Can I manually perform the functions that are found in the following script to install the extension and if so can someone kindly list the queries/steps I need to take to edit the SQL database?

```
<?php
if ( !function_exists( 'version_compare' ) || ( version_compare( phpversion(), '5.3.2' ) < 0 ) ) {
echo "You are using PHP version " . phpversion() . " but MediaWiki needs PHP 5.3.2 or higher. ABORTING.\n" .
"Check if you have a newer php executable with a different name, such as php5.\n";
die( 1 );
}

$wgUseMasterForMaintenance = true;
require_once( __DIR__ . '/Maintenance.php' );

/**
 * Maintenance script to run database schema updates.
 *
 * @ingroup Maintenance
 */
class UpdateMediaWiki extends Maintenance {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->mDescription = "MediaWiki database updater";
    $this->addOption( 'skip-compat-checks', 'Skips compatibility checks, mostly for developers' );
    $this->addOption( 'quick', 'Skip 5 second countdown before starting' );
    $this->addOption( 'doshared', 'Also update shared tables' );
    $this->addOption( 'nopurge', 'Do not purge the objectcache table after updates' );
    $this->addOption( 'force', 'Override when $wgAllowSchemaUpdates disables this script' );
}

function getDbType() {
    /* If we used the class constant PHP4 would give a parser error here */
    return 2 /* Maintenance::DB_ADMIN */;
}

function compatChecks() {
    $test = new PhpXmlBugTester();
    if ( !$test->ok ) {
        $this->error(
            "Your system has a combination of PHP and libxml2 versions which is buggy\n" .
            "and can cause hidden data corruption in MediaWiki and other web apps.\n" .
            "Upgrade to PHP 5.2.9 or later and libxml2 2.7.3 or later!\n" .
            "ABORTING (see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45996).\n",
            true );
    }

    $test = new PhpRefCallBugTester;
    $test->execute();
    if ( !$test->ok ) {
        $ver = phpversion();
        $this->error(
            "PHP $ver is not compatible with MediaWiki due to a bug involving\n" .
            "reference parameters to __call. Upgrade to PHP 5.3.2 or higher, or \n" .
            "downgrade to PHP 5.3.0 to fix this.\n" .
            "ABORTING (see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50394 for details)\n",
            true );
    }
}

function execute() {
    global $wgVersion, $wgTitle, $wgLang, $wgAllowSchemaUpdates;

    if( !$wgAllowSchemaUpdates && !$this->hasOption( 'force' ) ) {
        $this->error( "Do not run update.php on this wiki. If you're seeing this you should\n"
            . "probably ask for some help in performing your schema updates.\n\n"
            . "If you know what you are doing, you can continue with --force", true );
    }

    $wgLang = Language::factory( 'en' );
    $wgTitle = Title::newFromText( "MediaWiki database updater" );

    $this->output( "MediaWiki {$wgVersion} Updater\n\n" );

    wfWaitForSlaves( 5 ); // let's not kill databases, shall we? ;) --tor

    if ( !$this->hasOption( 'skip-compat-checks' ) ) {
        $this->compatChecks();
    } else {
        $this->output( "Skipping compatibility checks, proceed at your own risk (Ctrl+C to abort)\n" );
        wfCountdown( 5 );
    }

    # Attempt to connect to the database as a privileged user
    # This will vomit up an error if there are permissions problems
    $db = wfGetDB( DB_MASTER );

    $this->output( "Going to run database updates for " . wfWikiID() . "\n" );
    $this->output( "Depending on the size of your database this may take a while!\n" );

    if ( !$this->hasOption( 'quick' ) ) {
        $this->output( "Abort with control-c in the next five seconds (skip this countdown with --quick) ... " );
        wfCountDown( 5 );
    }

    $shared = $this->hasOption( 'doshared' );

    $updates = array( 'core', 'extensions', 'stats' );
    if( !$this->hasOption('nopurge') ) {
        $updates[] = 'purge';
    }

    $updater = DatabaseUpdater::newForDb( $db, $shared, $this );
    $updater->doUpdates( $updates );

    foreach( $updater->getPostDatabaseUpdateMaintenance() as $maint ) {
        if ( $updater->updateRowExists( $maint ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        $child = $this->runChild( $maint );
        $child->execute();
        $updater->insertUpdateRow( $maint );
    }

    $this->output( "\nDone.\n" );
}

function afterFinalSetup() {
    global $wgLocalisationCacheConf;

    # Don't try to access the database
    # This needs to be disabled early since extensions will try to use the l10n
    # cache from $wgExtensionFunctions (bug 20471)
    $wgLocalisationCacheConf = array(
        'class' => 'LocalisationCache',
        'storeClass' => 'LCStore_Null',
        'storeDirectory' => false,
        'manualRecache' => false,
    );
}
}

$maintClass = 'UpdateMediaWiki';
require_once( RUN_MAINTENANCE_IF_MAIN );
```

Comment: have you tried simply accessing it from the browser?

Comment: @asifrc Yes I have, but it tells me that it must be run through the commandline console.

Comment: By 'it', do you mean update.php or whatever instructions you're following?

Comment: @asifrc I mean update.php (typed www.site.net/directory/update.php in browser url)